# Reusing jquery animation

Tags: jquery

I need to run some simple animations multiple times. The only difference will be the ID of the div, #MenuBoxB, #MenuBoxC etc. Is there a way to reuse the following code?

```
$("#MenuBoxA")
  .delay(100)
  .queue(function(next){
    $(this).css('z-index', '3');
    next();
  });

$("#MenuBoxA")
  .animate({
    top: "+=59px",
    left: "+=20px",
    width: "-=10px",
    height: "-=10px"
  });
```

edit: Animation should look like this http://jsfiddle.net/b8evsr0m/, I think you'll understand what I ment by "reusing" when you see that huge javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an array containing `id`s of the `div` element and rotate array element on every click of `SideMenu_XyM` div as shown below -

```
$(function(){
     // array with div ids
     var array=['MenuBoxA_XyM','MenuBoxB_XyM','MenuBoxC_XyM','MenuBoxD_XyM','MenuBoxE_XyM','MenuBoxF_XyM','MenuBoxG_XyM'];
     var arrayLen = array.length;

    // bind click event to SideMenu
    $('#SideMenu_XyM').click(function(){

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-4]).delay(100).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '3'); next();}).animate({top: "+=59px", left: "+=20px", width: "-=10px", height: "-=10px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-3]).delay(100).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '2'); next();}).animate({top: "+=50px", left: "+=20px", width: "-=10px", height: "-=10px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-2]).delay(100).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '1'); next();}).animate({top: "+=40px", left: "+=20px", width: "-=10px", height: "-=10px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-1]).delay(100).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '0'); next();}).animate({top: "-=268px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-7]).delay(200).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '2'); next();}).animate({top: "+=30px", left: "-=20px", width: "+=10px", height: "+=10px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-6]).delay(200).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '3'); next();}).animate({top: "+=40px", left: "-=20px", width: "+=10px", height: "+=10px"});

       $('#'+array[arrayLen-5]).delay(200).queue(function(next){$(this).css('z-index', '4'); next();}).animate({top: "+=49px", left: "-=20px", width: "+=10px", height: "+=10px"});

    //rotate array elements position
    var last = array[arrayLen-1];
    for(var i= (arrayLen-1);i>0;i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    array[0] = last;
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b8evsr0m/11/)**

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that those animations will not be run at the same time for all divs. They should be run for each div individually when called.

Comment: On which event you are calling these `div`s? you can pass `$(this)` instead of `#MenuBoxA` if you are calling these two jquery on div `MenuBoxA`.

Comment: On mouse click. They are part of "some sort of" rotating menu I'm trying to make right now. I could post entire code, but It might be too long for ask/answer section.

Comment: Check the link I posted in my question. I hope you'll see why I need to reuse code. My English is not very good.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I have used an array for storing div ids and rotating them on every click.

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't even know that elements inside array can rotate places. Thank you very much.